# How to display selected item / value in twoway binding combobox?

Tags: wpf, binding

I have one combobox which have Mode twoway binding.
I binded combobox to list of family members(MemberId,MemberType) table.
I want to display selected Item (MemberType) from list..

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the `SelectedItem` property on the `ComboBox` to a property in your code-behind.

If you need to display this as a visual item, then you can do this by binding the `Content` of a `ContentPresenter` to that selected item.

As an example

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource={Binding Path=Collection} SelectedItem={Binding Path=MySelectedItem}/>
<ContentPresenter Content={Binding Path=MySelectedItem}/>
```

And in your code behind: (replacing "object" with whatever your colleciton is)

```
private object m_selectedItem;
public object MySelectedItem
{
    get { return m_selectedItem; }
    set
    {
        m_selectedItem = value;
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MySelectedItem"));
    }
}
```

You will have to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface in your code behind for this to work however

Comment: Also don't forget to set the ContentTemplateSelector to you favorite DataTemplateSelector. :)

Answer (score 0):

Bind SelectedItem to

```
public FamilyMember Selectedmember { get{...} set{...} }.....
```

and ensure that you call NotifyPropertyChanged methods in the setter for this member.

Then you can bind other objects on the view to this SelectedMember and display any information you may need.